# How to group and sum data and return the biggest sum in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, sum

Let's say my data looks like this:

| news_title | company |
| --- | --- |
| string | Facebook |
| string | Facebook |
| string | Amazon |
| string | Apple |
| string | Amazon |
| string | Facebook |

How can I group the companies and get name and the number for the company with the biggest sum?

I want be able to print something like :

Facebook was mentioned in the news the most - 24 times.

I tried this but it did not work the way I wanted:

```
df.groupby("company").sum()
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `value_counts`:

```
>>> df.company.value_counts().head(1)
Facebook    3
Name: company, dtype: int64
```

**Update**:

> Could you please tell me how I could go about printing it out in a sentence?

```
company, count = list(df.company.value_counts().head(1).items())[0]
print(f'{company} was mentioned in the news the most - {count} times.')

# Output:
Facebook was mentioned in the news the most - 3 times.
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me how I could go about printing it out in a sentence?  Something like "Facebook was mentioned in the news the most - 3 times."

Comment: @Domi. I updated my answer. Can you check it, please?